# Find matching record from master table using vb.net sql server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to make application (using vb.net and sql server) that find matching record from a static Master Table. The Master Table looks like this

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Pkey</th>
    <th>Item1</th> 
    <th>Item2</th>
    <th>Item3</th>
    <th>Item4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>Apple</td> 
    <td>Hat</td>
    <td>Stroberry</td>
    <td>Car</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Blue</td>
    <td>Ocean</td> 
    <td>Sky</td>
    <td>Light</td>
    <td>Moon</td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Yellow</td>
    <td>Sun</td> 
    <td>Pokemon</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>Banana</td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>Tree</td> 
    <td>Leave</td>
    <td>Tea</td>
    <td>Energy</td>
    
  </tr>
</table>
```

And then there is one table that consist of one column with the value for example

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Realtime Check</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Energy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Stroberry</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It will give result 
Red; Item1,Item3 and
Green; Item4. Help me please.

Comment: Search and then use an appropriate HTML parser library.

Comment: What is you question?

Comment: Nyoman, I think you need to ask a clear question here. This is a VB.net/SQL application? If so, can you provide the SQL schema for the table, and how you wish to apply that in the UI please?

Comment: I' so sorry for my poor English. Actually i'd like to make a vb.net application which is scanning sql server table's changes in realtime and then if the changes meet some criteria then the app will save this data change into mysql database (planning for sms gateway using gammu). The table structure is like this